# Expo XDE "timeout of 60000 ms exceeded"?

Tags: react-native-ios, expo

I am using Expo XDE to create a new project for my first react native application.

But whenever I click on "create new project", it starts downloading some stuff and errors out. Don't know where to increase this timeout value, I checked the documentation of expo but could not find anything related to this. Any leads here is really appreciated.

Please note that I installed expo xde-2.22.0.dmg on mac OS High Sierra version 10.13 (17A405)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like someone reported this issue to expo after reading [this question](https://github.com/expo/xde/issues/153).

An update to XDE is made that increases the timeout. Upgrading to XDE v2.22.1 should fix this.

Comment: Why down-voting? Are people mad or what, think twice before acting foolish.

Comment: i am using update version but same issue please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up using react-native init then porting the project over to expo [Expo Docs](https://github.com/expo/xde#converting-an-existing-project-to-work-with-expo)  on how to convert a project to work with expo

Comment: oh okay, good to know that I am not the only one suffering :P