# Error in Expo XDE 2.22.1

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

Based on the suggestion in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377240/expo-xde-timeout-of-60000-ms-exceeded), I upgraded Expo to 2.22.1. But on opening my project in this version of expo I am getting below error.

Any leads here is really appreciated.

Error running `xcrun simctl openurl booted exp://localhost:19000`: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):

The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out
Operation timed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the cache of your iOS simulator, close Expo XDE and run it all again.

For resetting, go `Hardware -> Erase all content and settings`.

`Error code: 60` can usually be solved with the simulator's reset, although your case may be different.

Comment: I am using mac, I am not sure where to find Hardware -> Erase all content and settings.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal in the application actions ribbon, top of the screen.